# How to Create a Row for Each Row from Another Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Users table and a Memberships table. A User can have many Memberships, paid or unpaid recurring on a yearly basis. I want to create a new row in Membership for each User in Users, as a Free member.

Membership is currently empty so I'll have to create new ids for each row automatically.

Membership is laid out as:

```
[Id]
[StartDateTime]
[EndDateTime]
[Frozen]
[MembershipType]
[PaidDateTime]
```

And User is

```
[Id]
  ,[AspUserId]
  ,[Title]
  ,[Forename]
  ,[Surname]
  ,[Email]
  ,[Dob]
  ,[DateCreated]
  ,[AddressId]
  ,[PhoneNumber]
  ,[Gender]
  ,[Nationality]
  ,[WMSFPlayerId]
  ,[ProfileImageURL]
  ,[FavouriteGame]
  ,[Bio]
  ,[Username]
  ,[LastLogin]
  ,[WMSFPlayerId_Confirmed]
  ,[MembershipId]
```

In Membership:

- ID will be a new id
- StartDateTime will be today
- End Date Time will be a year from today
- Frozen will be 0
- MembershipType will 0
- PaidDateTime will be null

How can I insert a Free Membership into the Membership table for each User I have in Users? I'll have to also update the Users table with the new MembershipID that was created for them.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @TabAlleman Updated!

Comment: Please google and learn about the INSERT..SELECT command in SQL.

Comment: Welcome to SO or kind of ... @Powellellogram. What have you done ...?

Comment: @TabAlleman But my Users table will also have to be updated with a MembershipID FK from the Membership table

Comment: Yes, the UPDATE command is also well documented and can be easily googled as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would like to point out that your table definitions won't support the requirement of having multiple memberships per user. What you have right now is multiple users per membership. The user table should not have the `MembershipID` field. It should be removed from the `User` table and a `UserID` field should be added to the `Membership` table. Once that's done something like,

```
INSERT INTO Membership (Id, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, Frozen, MembershipType)
SELECT Id, GETDATE(), GETDATE(), 0, 'Free' FROM User
```

Obviously you'll need to change the values based on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You would use `insert . . . select`.  Something like this:

```
insert into memberships(id, StartDate, EndDate, Frozen, MembershipType, PaidDateTime)
    select u.aspuserid, getdate(), dateadd(year, 1, getdate()), 0, 0, null
    from users u;
```

Comment: Probably trying to insert the userid into the StartDate column would cause an error.